# Mass Effect 2: Romance and Kelly and Liara

Tags: mass-effect-2

I've been playing (and loving) Mass Effect 2 as Femshep, and I just finished the excellent Shadow Broker DLC.

Here's my problem: I romanced Liara in ME1, but in ME2 she wasn't around, so I started having fun with Kelly. We've been flirty, and had dinner, and now she's feeding my fishes.

Then I got the Shadow Broker DLC and, at the end, there's the inevitable conversation with Liara: "What about us?"

Is Liara a valid love interest in ME2? If so, could telling her that I want to get back together ruin things with me and Kelly (especially in regard to ME3)?

Right now I value my relationship with Kelly more, so I don't want to jepordize that by saying to Liara that I'm still interested... But I'm also intrigued by the effects of having Liara "on the hook" in ME3. Will reaffirming things with Liara ruin my chances with Kelly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you carried over your romance with Liara from ME 1, the relationship carries over into ME 2. But your love interest will not join your squad. You will see their picture in your cabin. It is possible to pursue someone in ME 2. In this case your love interest's picture is turned upside down.

[Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance) says if you do this it does have an adverse effect on your relationship in ME 3 if you wish to pursue the same love interest.

EDIT:

Reaffirming things with Liara will not affect your chances with Kelly in ME 2.

Comment: I just want to note that, on one series of playthroughs, I romanced Liara in ME1, then fooled around with Miranda in ME2 (cause SUICIDE mission... and also dat A), patched it up with Liara in the Shadow Broker, and then continued the Liara romance in ME3.